# Acrobat Pro DC not showing saved PDF

Tags: pdf, export, adobe-acrobat

I created a basic resume in Adobe Illustrator CC and then saved it as a PDF. However when I opened the PDF in Acrobat Pro DC the only thing that appears is  my small logo that I had in the upper right-hand corner of the resume. The actual text from the resume does not appear at all.

Is there something that I need to click on to make the actual text document  in the AI document to be saved completely and appear as a  complete PDF? I have been using Acrobat for many years and have never had this problem.

Comment: Check your artboard size in Illustrator.

Answer (score -1):

Check you don't have the layer set as non printing

Comment: Hey Cherelyn, welcome to GD.SE! Can you add a little more detail to your answer? (Where would they find that layer setting, for example?)